# Unable to compile c++11 libraries despite having added -std=c++11 in platform.txt

Tags: arduino-ide, c++, compilation-errors

I want to use c++ data structures such as vectors, arrays, map... in my Arduino sketch. I made sure to **add -std=c++11 and -std=gnu++11 in platform.txt**, I am still getting the following error message:

> fatal error: unordered_map: No such file or directory
> #include <unordered_map> compilation terminated. exit status 1 unordered_map: No such file or directory

Here's a snapshot from ~/arduino-nightly/hardware/arduino/avr/platform.txt:

[image]

Versions:

- Arduino ide: 1.8.14
- g++: 5.4.0
- avr-g++: 4.9.2

**What else should I set up?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AVR-based Arduinos don't come with anything close to a full C++ standard library implementation.  They have [avr-libc](https://nongnu.org/avr-libc/) which is fairly complete to at least the [C99 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), that is the C standard from 1999, not C++.  What you're doing with `-std=c++11` is influencing the standard used by the compiler to interpret the C++ language itself.  This does work fine on AVR based Arduinos, but is not going to give you the sort of C++ containers you may be used to on a desktop or larger embedded system, like an ESP8266.

Much of the C++ standard library would be completely out of place on an AVR based Arduino, particularly those parts that make use of dynamic allocation like `unordered_map` in your error message.

There are *some* parts of the C++ library implemented via [Arduino STL](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinostl/).  Whether or not you *should* be using containers from it is another question.

If you do try to use Arduino STL, I'd encourage you to use more conservative parts of it.  Something like an `unordered_map`, but with less (or no) dynamic allocation could be implemented by using Arduino STL's `std::array` and functions from its `<algorithm>` header, like their `std::find` or `std::lower_bound`, etc.  Trying to use a C++ `map` or `vector` container or something of that sort is kind of asking for trouble, more so on the more common AVR-based Arduinos with only roughly 2 Kbyte of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you show me a way to use std::array in arduino (I am having trouble #including<array>)